# how to access attributes of model fields in templates in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

I have been used the following two urls in my code.
In the first case, I access pk of object using `underscore`. In the second case, I do `.pk`.
For the first one, changing `underscore` to `.pk` does not make any difference. but for the second one
template throws `reverseMatch` error? why is it? what is the rule behind field access of objects in templates and views?

```
<a href="{% url 'search_update' pk=search_pk %}">Edit</a> 
<a href="{% url 'postings_list' pk=post.pk %}" Posting </a>
```

Comment: Can you share the urls.py. Does the postings_list url expect a pk?

Comment: It looks like search_pk and search.pk do return valid values for reverse matching your search_update url. post.pk and post_pk do not. You may try to show the values in your template by something like {{ post.pk }} and {{ post_pk }}.

Answer (score -2):

There is no such thing as a single underscore syntax in Django templates. The only way this would give a valid result is if you were explicitly passing a variable named `search_pk` into the template from your view.